# How to add a column to a table imported in Excel via Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table imported in Excel using power query, the table looks like:

| Department | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| HR | 100 |
| HR | 300 |

What I want to do is to add a column "Percentage" without modifying the source file but just by adding it in Excel and fill it just in excel.

The final version should be:

| Department | Cost | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 100 | 3% |
| HR | 300 | 10% |

The problem is that the additional column will be available only in the excel and not in Power Query editor. I'd like it to be present also in the power query editor.

Another solution I tried is to add a custom empty (just with null) column "percentage" in the Power query editor. Once it is uploaded in and filled manually in Excel, if the query is refreshed the data added manually in excel in column "Percentage" are lost.

I'd like to import the table just with the two columns "Department" and "Cost" and then fill the "Percentage" column manually in Excel.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can turn your precentage table into an excel table (if it isn't already) and then use `DATA => Get\Transform data area => From Table\Range` to get the table into the query, combine the tables there, then you get the combined data loaded into the excel sheet.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how 100 can be 3% and 300 be 10% (rounding?), but .. rather than loading powerquery as a table, load it as a pivot table report and then change the column in the pivot table to return a % column total

[image]